# ExclusionFilter for TriggeredSendDefinition

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk

I can't seem to get Exclusion lists working for my triggered Sends from TriggeredSendDefinitions.

I want to try my luck with Exclusion Filters, are there any examples of these being used anywhere?

I assume I would populate a data-extension 'exclusion_DE', and then in the Exclusion filter, I would throw in some 'where not in exclusion_DE', or something like that.

I can't find anything that says how to actually form the exclusion criteria? Can anyone point me to an example/ more explicit description.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an example here, not for TriggeredSendDefinitions in particular, but for User-initiated-Emails, I believe the exclusion filters work the same.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_messages/how_to_create_a_user_initiated_email_interaction/

`ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("exclusion_DE","EMAIL_ADDR", EMAIL_ADDR))>0`